# Create two actions on the same view file in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp, routes

I have a profile page where the url looks like this:
`/ClinicalAnnotation/Participants/profile/11`

I want to create this `/ClinicalAnnotation/Participants/profile/11/submitreview/1`

How can I do this with routes?

**Also:**
On this profile page I have an `<a href="">` tag.

```
<a href="/ClinicalAnnotation/Participants/profile/'.$participantId.'/submitreview/'$medicalRecordReviewId'">Medical Record Review 2 Completed</span>
```

So I want to create an action in my ParticipantsController.php:

```
public function submitreview($participantId, $medicalRecordReviewId)
{
    echo "Hello";
}
```

There's also a file called PermissionManagerComponent.php. I have to add the permissions here, something like:

```
'Controller/ClinicalAnnotation/Participants/submitreview' => 'Controller/ClinicalAnnotation/Participants/profile',
```

Right now when a User clicks on the a tag, I want to see the word `Hello`. Then I'll know what I'm trying to do is working.

Attached is a screenshot of the page and the `<a href="">` tag (bottom right portion of the screenshot).
[image]

Comment: Please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: This question is very disorganized, it's not clear what your real problem is, or if you're trying to ask 3 questions in one, or what. My first question to you is whether the URL needs to be `/ClinicalAnnotation/Participants/profile/11/submitreview/1`, or if `/ClinicalAnnotation/Participants/submitreview/11/1` would work? The latter is very straight-forward and follows Cake conventions, so it needs no special routing to work.

Comment: Sorry 2.10. It’s an old project. Thank you.

Comment: @Greg Schmidt Sorry.```/ClinicalAnnotation/Participants/submitreview/11/1``` could work.
But I made a mistake I think I'll need a form here instead of an ```<a>``` tag. How can I create an action in my controller and then create a Form that points to it?

Comment: To create an action in your controller, you just create a function with that name in your controller. To create a form that points to it, you use the Form helper and pass it a URL array that specifies that action. This is pretty basic stuff, honestly, it's all well covered in the documentation.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I've been assigned this project while a) never used cakephp before and b) so much custom code has been written, it's very very disorganized and messy.

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom route elements to form pretty much any URL you want, something along the lines of this:

```php
Router::connect(
    '/ClinicalAnnotation/Participants/profile/:participantId/submitreview/:medicalRecordReviewId',
    array(
        'controller' => 'Participants',
        'action' => 'submitreview',
    ),
    array(
        // pass route element values to the controller action
        'pass' => array(
            'participantId',
            'medicalRecordReviewId',
        ),
        // restrict route elements to integer values
        'participantId' => '[0-9]+',
        'medicalRecordReviewId' => '[0-9]+',
    )
);
```

To generate a link in your templates you can then use the helpers, for example:

```php
echo $this->Html->link('Medical Record Review 2 Completed', array(
    'prefix' => null,
    'plugin' => false,
    'controller' => 'Participants',
    'action' => 'submitreview',
    'participantId' => $participantId,
    'medicalRecordReviewId' => $medicalRecordReviewId,
));
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Development > Routing > Passing Parameters to Action](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/development/routing.html#passing-parameters-to-action)**
- **[Cookbook > Development > Routing > Reverse Routing](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/development/routing.html#reverse-routing)**
- **[Cookbook > Views > Helpers > HtmlHelper > link()](https://book.cakephp.org/2/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper::link)**